# #if compilation directive for library

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation

I am working on an application that can be compiled on different platforms. I want to check at compile time if a library is available.

Basically, here is what i want to do

```
#if LIBRARY_OK(mylib)
using mylib;
using mylib.subpackage;
#endif
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, but you can configure different builds with different conditional compilation symbols.

Answer (score 1):

> This C# application can be compiled on different platforms.

Then, instead of attempting to check whether the library is available, define compilation symbols for the different platforms that you are going to support. For example:

- Debug (Windows) => #DEBUG, #TRACE, #LIBRARYX
- Debug (Android) => #DEBUG, #TRACE
- Release (Windows) => #LIBRARYX
- etc, etc, etc

Then, you would do basically the same as your code:

```
#if LIBRARYX
using mylib;
using mylib.subpackage;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be a little weird and and not very elegant, but it works. 
Put this command to your `Pre-build event`s in your project properties. The following command assume that your files is in your root directory, but you can modify `Program.cs`'s location.

```
if exist C:\ffmpeg (
set IS_LIB_OK=TRUE
)

if %IS_LIB_OK% equ TRUE echo using mylib;  > $(ProjectDir)\Temp.cs & echo using mylib.extension; >> $(ProjectDir)\Temp.cs
type $(ProjectDir)\Program.cs >> $(ProjectDir)\Temp.cs
del $(ProjectDir)\Program.cs
type $(ProjectDir)\Temp.cs > $(ProjectDir)\Program.cs
del  $(ProjectDir)\Temp.cs
```

This will attach

```
using mylib;
using mylib.extensions;
```

if a `ffmpeg library` is in your C drive, but you can check it with any batch command that is right for your solution.